# How to query item's metadata from Couchbase?

Tags: nosql, metadata, couchbase

I put some data to CouchBase 1.8.1,and get it successful.But I want to query its metadata,as expiration and att_reason(non-json or json).In some document,it list the metadata with json format,for example:

```
{
 "_id" : "contact_475",
 "_rev" : "1-AB9087AD0977F089",
 "_bin" : "...",
 "$flags" : 0,
 "$expiration" : 0,
 "name" : "Fred Bloggs",
}
```

How can I query item's metadata?

Comment: At least you can do it using Views in Couchbase 2.0.

Comment: THX.I change to Couchbase 2.0,and get those metadata from view successfully.But I just store some simple data and don't want to use view.Is there any other way can get common item metadata?

Answer (score 0):

As Pavel the most common way to access metadata in Couchbase (2.0) is using Views.

You can also use the internal TAP protocol :
http://www.couchbase.com/wiki/display/couchbase/TAP+Protocol

Could you give us more information about your use case and why you need to access meta/expiration ? And why you cannot use views (that is the recommended way to do it)

Regards
Tug

Comment: I just try to put php's session into Couchbase by php-pecl-memcache module.But the session has expiration,and I want to check its value.[This article](http://nitschinger.at/How-to-store-PHP-sessions-in-Couchbase) says $expiration is 0.It's different between memcache and actual test.The TAP protocol seems difficult for me,but I will try,thanks a lot.

Comment: When using Couchbase the recommended way is to use the Couchbase Client SDK available here http://www.couchbase.com/develop The SDK allows the application to be well integrated Couchbase cluster.


About the PHP and Session Management I will invite you to read these articles from Michael, one of the Couchbase Developer Evangelist :


http://nitschinger.at/How-to-store-PHP-sessions-in-Couchbase


http://nitschinger.at/Using-Couchbase-as-a-flexible-session-store

Comment: THX.I have found those artiles via google and try.It's good articles.But I though some metadata like expiration is a important parameter.If can get that,as use 'memcache dump' command display.It's better.

Comment: I would suggest using a view, it will have better performance than the dump command, once you have more than a few sessions stored.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is issuing an HTTP request to:
`http://serveraddress:8091/couchBase/default/contact_475`

The response should contain an `X-Couchbase-Meta` header with the metadata. More information is here: http://xmeblog.blogspot.co.il/2013/08/couchbase-how-to-retrieve-key.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the meta data in a Couchbase query you can do something like this:

```
SELECT meta(b).* FROM bucket b
```

You can also see both meta data and all other data in a query by doing something like this:

```
SELECT meta(b).*, * FROM bucket b
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to query only meta data using [N1QL](https://www.couchbase.com/products/n1ql) you could run below query, it will return all meta data about document :

```
select meta(bucket_name) from bucket_name
```

But if you want to get these information from [Sync Gateway](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/current/guides/sync-gateway/index.html) it will return to you by every GET request using [REST API](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/current/references/sync-gateway/rest-api/index.html), the REST API also include some filtering above these meta data.