# ElasticSearch - Map _type to one of the field in document

Tags: elasticsearch

We transfer data from Couchbase to ElasticSearch. When we transfer the data to ES the _type field value becomes 'couchbaseDocument'. Instead of this we want to point _type field to one of the field in the JSON document.

Is it possible?

Below is the sample document -

```
{
    "UserID": 1,
    "Type": "UserDocument",
    "Username": "User1",
    "UserAssignments": [
        { "Role": "Role1", "Permission": "P2" },
        { "Role": "Role2", "Permission": "P1" }
    ]
}
```

I want to map "Type" field to "_type" field.

We use below classes to push the data to Couchbase using Couchbase .NET SDK.

```
public class UserDetails
{
        public int UserID { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }       
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public List<Assignments> UserAssignments { get; set; }
}

public class UserAssignments
{
        public string Role { get; set; }
        public string Permission { get; set; }
}
```

The link you provided is outdated. So i used Couchbase views to get metadata for the document. PSB metadata for the above document.

```
{
    "total_rows": 1,
    "rows": [
        { "id": "1", "key": "1", "value": { "id": "1", "rev": "2-13e4e93ffafcbcc30000000000000000", "expiration": 0, "flags": 0, "type": "json" } }
    ]
}
```

Hope this is what you were looking for.

Thanks,
Sameer

Comment: Can you show what values the field you want to use as the type can have?

Comment: Updated the post with example. Thanks

Comment: Can you also show the metadata of your couchbase document as it is stored in Couchbase? Elasticsearch will receive both the metadata and document content and I'd like to see how your metadata looks like.

Comment: We generally push data to couchbase using C#. NET classes.

I have updated the post with class structure.Please let me know if you are looking for this? I can not see metadata for documents in Couchbase.

Comment: See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13332816/how-to-query-items-metadata-from-couchbase) to get the matadata of your couchbase document. Please update your question with whatever you find out.

Comment: Updated the document. Thank you so much for looking in.

Comment: I have updated the post with metadata. Let me know if you need any more details. Thanks much for your time and help.